# React Router v. 1.0.0-rc3 Parameter in Path Matching Fixed Path Too

Tags: react-router, reactjs

I'm using react-router v. 1.0.0-rc3 and I have a route configuration as follows:

```html
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="track/:id" component={Track} />
    <Route path="track/new/" component={NewTrack} />
</Route>
```

When I navigate to `track/new/`, it is matching the `track/:id` path and the component `Track` gets used. This didn't happen before. Do I need to change my paths or is there any way to keep this path format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just swap them around:

```jsx
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="track/new" component={NewTrack} />
  <Route path="track/:id" component={Track} />
</Route>
```